# Convert PySpark DataFrame struct column to string of key-value pairs

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a struct with a large number of key-value pairs:

```
|-- struct_col: struct (nullable = false)
|    |-- key1: string (nullable = false)
|    |-- key2: string (nullable = false)
|    |-- key3: string (nullable = false)
|    |-- key4: string (nullable = false)
|    |-- key5: string (nullable = false)
|    |-- (... and so on ...)
```

I want to turn this into a long string of key-value pairs concatenated together like so:

```
key1=var1&key2=var2&key3=var3&key4=var4&...
```

So far I have tried this:

```
fn.concat_ws("&", *[f"struct_col.{col}" for col in df.select(fn.col("struct_col.*")).columns])
```

However this only concatenates the values. I know `to_json` exists using a workflow like [this one here](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/transform-complex-data-types-scala.html), however I would like to use different separators for the key-value pairs and the concatenated struct fields. I would also like to do this dynamically as there is a possibility the struct fields change.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add one more `concat_ws` inside the list comprehension:

```py
F.concat_ws("&", *[F.concat_ws("=", F.lit(col), F.col(f"struct_col.{col}")) for col in df.select(F.col("struct_col.*")).columns])
```